# Problems to get followed sites with Hybrid Profile

Tags: user-profile, following, hybrid-solution

I'm trying to get the followed sites of the current user without success. 
I'm working on Sharepoint 2016 On-Premise but the Profile is Hybrid so the remote profile site is something like:

```
https://xyz-my.sharepoint.com/personal/my_name_my_tenant
```

but in my local environment its something as below:

```
https://localsite.local.it
```

My code is:

```
SPServiceContext serverContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
UserProfile profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(loginName);
profile.FollowedContent.GetItems(FollowedContentQueryOptions.Sites, 0);
```

but the result is "Personal site does not exists"

> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.SocialDataStoreException:
>   PersonalSiteNotFound : Il sito personale non esiste. at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.SPS2SAppUtility.GetPersonalUrl(UserProfile&
>   profile) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.SPS2SAppExecutionContext.InitializeForProfile()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.SPS2SAppExecutionContext.EnsureInitialized()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.SPS2SAppExecutionContextBase.get_IsLocal()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContent.GetItems(FollowedContentQueryOptions
>   options, Int32 subtype)

How can I get the current user followed sites on-premise where the profile is hybrid so the personal site is remote?

Note: the local server is correctly configured because I can click on the star

Answer (score 0):

You have to request it from SPO. The local UPSA is reporting correctly, you do not have an on-prem Personal Site. The thing is, you don't need the personal site address, you can use REST or CSOM to get values for the current user.

For example you can get all followed content with REST:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=14)
```

If all you want is sites use:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=4)
```

Comment: I've tried with REST e CSOM calling the Sharepoint Online API but there starts a total different scenario with Authentication questions about CORS, SP Add-In, Implicit Flow, ADAL etc. To cut out, I want to know if a local server side solution, with classical Sharepoint Object Model could work in the Hybrid Environment.

Comment: No, because the local UPSA is not used to store follows.

Comment: Ok the local UPSA does not store follows but is an Hybrid environment so one think is possibile to query the local system and get the remote data. In the Search Engine counterpart of the Sharepoint Hybrid system it works. I can query locally (with the right reference) and get the remote Search Index values.

Comment: The local query is just sent to the cloud, it is not processed locally. I didn't write the system, I am just explaining how it works. The follows are stored in SPO.